# Pushing Cuckoo Eggs under Inverse Radon Transforms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integral-transforms

Essentially the inverse of the [Radon transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform)s $Rf(L)=\int_L{f(x)|dx|}$  has the ability to reconstruct $f(x)$ from the integrals over all lines; or, expressed differently to (re)construct $f(x)$  from a functional, that maps lines to real values.

Essentially this question is aimed at cuckoo eggs the inverse Radon transform will hatch if pushed under it:

**Question:**

what are examples of other functionals, that map lines to real values, to which the inverse Radon transform can be applied beneficially?

I am especially interested in examples that have been mentioned in publications.
Two examples of such line functionals that would be possible candidates, are

- mapping lines to the geodesic distance between the pair of points, in which they intersect the boundary of a compact, convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (lines that miss the boundary or are tangent to it are mapped to $0$)
- mapping lines to their moments of inertia w.r.t. the model of a compact physical object; lines missing a sufficiently small compact containing volume will be mapped to $0$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $S\subset \bR^n$ is a compact semialgebraic set. Denote by $AL_n$ the   Grassmannian of affine lines in $\bR^n$. We define a "motivic" Radon transform that  associates to each line $L\in AL_n$ the Euler characteristic  $R_S(L):=\chi(L\cap S)$. Pierre Schapira showed that the set $S$ is completely determined by its motivic Radon transform  $R_S: AL_n\to \mathbb{Z}$.

This problem  can be formulated  cleverly  to express  $1_S$, the indicator function of $S$,  as an inverse Radon transform of $R_S$.  The story is very rich and a bit too  complex to expose here. Instead I refer to  section 4.1 and 4.2   of [my notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/conormal_curv.pdf) where you will find detailed explanations and precise references.  Also, here [is a link to Schapira's original paper.](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.schapira/respapers/TomoLN.pdf)

The Crofton formulae  allow you  to  compute certain invariants of $S$ given the knowledge of  other invariants of the intersection of $S$ with affine planes.